# How can I break the inner loop, take next element from the outer loop, and then continue the inner loop from the point where it was interrupted

Tags: python-3.x

How to realize the following pseudocode:

```
a = [110,95,70,40]
b = [100, 90, 80, 75, 60]
for i in a:
    for z in b:
        if i>=z:
            some action, then
            take next element in the outer loop, but continue 
            from the point where it was stopped in the inner loop
```

Due to both arrays are sorted there is no reason to go back and restart inner loop

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? Please see [ask].

Comment: *take next element in the outer loop, but continue from the point where it was stopped in the inner loop* -- for only the next outer element or all the remaining outer elements?

Comment: @dawg for all the remaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a variable, `bi`, to keep track of your position in `b`:

```
bi = 0 
for av in a:
    while bi < len(b):
        if av >= b[bi]:
            print([av,b[bi]])
            break
        bi += 1
```